# Nested IFs with VLOOKUPS, 3rd condition not executing

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula that calculates a value using 3 variables so I had to make a Frankenstein of a formula to make it work before I even went the VBA route.

```
=IF('TilePIx BOM_Launch'!E16=4, VLOOKUP('TilePIx BOM_Launch'!D16,Shipping!Q8:S14, IF('TilePIx BOM_Launch'!C16="Ground", 3, 2), FALSE), IF('TilePIx BOM_Launch'!E16=5, VLOOKUP('TilePIx BOM_Launch'!D16,Shipping!Q15:S21,IF('TilePIx BOM_Launch'!C16="Ground", 3, 2), FALSE), IF('TilePIx BOM_Launch'!E16=6, VLOOKUP('TilePIx BOM_Launch'!E16, Shipping!Q22:S28, IF('TilePIx BOM_Launch'!C16="Ground", 3, 2),FALSE), "n/a")))
```

Basically, excel is not calculating the result when BOM_Launch!E16=6.

Dont know why, but 4 & 5 are working flawlessly.

Comment: Try to just debug that section instead of the entire formula at once. i.e. debug `=VLOOKUP('TilePIx BOM_Launch'!E16, Shipping!Q22:S28, IF('TilePIx BOM_Launch'!C16="Ground", 3, 2),FALSE)`

Comment: Also, what do you mean by not calculating? Returning error? Wrong result? idk?

Comment: If statement is for 2 conditions, the code does not look "nested" enough for me. When using VBA, try CASE statement (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement)

Comment: FYI If the E16/D16 is the cause of your error, then your formula could be reduced to `=IF(AND(E16>=4,E16<=6),VLOOKUP(D16,INDEX(Q:Q,(E16-4)*7+8):INDEX(S:S,(E16-4)*7+14), IF(C16="Ground", 3, 2), FALSE),NA())`

Comment: @urdearboy No bugs in the formula, formula is doing what it's instructed to. Look at the answer below from  I Like Excel Very Much. And the formula was calculating but referencing the wrong cell to look up.

Comment: @HilaDG It's nested correctly the lack of syntax errors made that evident. Plus I'm trying my best for a non VBA solution although I would be more comfortable in VBA. Solution is below by @I Like Excel Very Much

Comment: @chrisneilsen I made an error in the last VLOOKUP. That reduction blew my mind BTW. Check the solution by @I Like Excel Very Much below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

`IF('TilePIx BOM_Launch'!E16=6, VLOOKUP('TilePIx BOM_Launch'!`**E16**`, Shipping!Q22:S28, IF('TilePIx BOM_Launch'!C16="Ground", 3, 2),FALSE), "n/a")))`

to

`IF('TilePIx BOM_Launch'!E16=6, VLOOKUP('TilePIx BOM_Launch'!`**D16**`, Shipping!Q22:S28, IF('TilePIx BOM_Launch'!C16="Ground", 3, 2),FALSE), "n/a")))`

It's referencing a different cell than the other VLOOKUP()'s.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thanks! Now I feel dumb AF 

Comment: A small typo in a equation this long is quit reasonable haha. Good eye guy who likes excel very much :)